# How to check if a constant is defined in Crystal

Tags: metaprogramming, crystal-lang

I need to verify if a constant is defined to do a conditional.

I was trying this but "defined" method not exists on this language:

```
if defined(constant)
  value = :foo
else
  value = :bar
end
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [macro](https://crystal-lang.org/docs/syntax_and_semantics/macros.html) and [TypeNode#has_constant?](https://crystal-lang.org/api/0.23.1/Crystal/Macros/TypeNode.html#has_constant%3F%28name%3AStringLiteral%7CSymbolLiteral%29%3ABoolLiteral-instance-method):

```
FOO = 1

value = nil
{% if @type.has_constant? "FOO" %}
  value = :foo
{% else %}
  value = :bar
{% end %}

pp value #=> :foo
```

Or even better, you can write a short custom macro for this:

```
macro toplevel_constant_defined?(c)
  {{ @type.has_constant? c }}
end

pp toplevel_constant_defined? "FOO" # => true
pp toplevel_constant_defined? "BAR" # => false
```

**Note:** as mentioned by [Jonne Haß](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2199687/jonne-ha%C3%9F), you only ever should need this in advanced macro programming, everywhere else it's a huge code smell, regardless of the language used.

Comment: Though it should be noted that you only ever should need this in advanced macro programming, everywhere else it's a huge code smell, regardless of the language used.